# Java Ui panel added at run time but it takes lot of time

Tags: java, netbeans

HELLO,

In my software application i used netbeans ui panel which is added at run time but not geeting satisfactory loading speed of the panel,how can i increase my loading of panel at runtime ANY METHOD OR WAY OF COADING WHICH MIGHT IMPORVE THE LOADING SPEED

THANKS IN ADVANCE

Comment: maybe you need to SHOUT LOUDER

Comment: insufficient info, @skaffman +1

Comment: Try overclocking the processor!

Comment: Or just getting a faster computer.  Seriously though, how can you expect anyone to even guess what's wrong or how to help given the scant amount of information you provide?

Answer (score 0):

1. Isolate the issue by removing items (commenting code out), until you get the speed you are looking and find the problem. It would be surprising that it is the panel, I imagine the root cause is some sort of database access or file loading issue.
2. Next time build the GUI by hand instead of using Netbeans.